# Run already deployed job on Flink Cluster using RestClusterClient

Tags: java, rest, apache-flink

I am trying to run already deployed job on Flink Cluster using Rest request.

I had success using a simple rest client

`POST http://localhost:8081/v1/jars/13775a71-0723-4c62-979b-7e9a9de3a0dc_some.jar/run
{
    "programArgsList" : ["test1", "test2"]
}`

But I would like to do it from Java and since there already is a RestClusterClient I would love to use that but it is poorly documented

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/client/program/rest/RestClusterClient.html

From what I see from the code it looks like there is no such possibility with this RestClusterClient

It looks like it is following closely features implemnted in CLI and documented here https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/cli.html so any `run` command requires passing a jar with the job.

There is no possibility to run already deployed job with this client. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Flink's cluster REST API has been designed to work with any REST client. The `RestClusterClient` which comes with the `flink-clients` module is intended for internal usage. However, you can also use it directly by instantiating it with a correctly set up Flink `Configuration`.

The `Configuration` is used to retrieve the cluster REST endpoint. Hence, if you configure the wrong REST address or the wrong HA mode, then the `RestClusterClient` might not be able to talk to the cluster. If you know where the `flink-conf.yaml` with which you have started the cluster is, then I would recommend to use `GlobalConfiguration#loadConfiguration(configurationDirectory)` to load it. This should give you a good starting point.

Once you have started the `RestClusterClient` you can interact with the cluster via

- `submitJob`: Submit a new job (only supported if you have a session cluster deployed)
- `requestJobResult`: Result of a job execution; if it's a streaming job, then this might never complete
- `cancel`: Cancel the given job
- `triggerSavepoint`: Trigger a savepoint and return its path
- `listJobs`: List all currently running jobs on the cluster
- and some more calls

Comment: Thank you for your response. Like I said earlier I did reviewed the `RestClusterClient` code and I noticed that you cannot run the already deployed job which I am after. I hoped that maybe I have missed something but from your response looks like I have not and there is no possibility to run already deployed job. All `run` methods require to pass ether jar or class which will be deployed and this is not what I need.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with run an already deployed job? Do you mean a job whose jars has been uploaded via the web UI before?

Comment: exactly. I can run it using rest API `POST http://localhost:8081/v1/jars/some_jar_id/run`

Comment: The RestClusterClient currently does not support this. Feel free to open a JIRA issue and to provide a fix for it.